# $C=\{\frac{n^2+12n+32}{n+5}\:|\:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Prove that $\inf C=\frac{45}{6}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Define $C=\{\frac{n^2+12n+32}{n+5}\:|\:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Prove that $\inf C=\frac{45}{6}$

*Attempt*:
We'll show that $\frac{45}{6}$ is a lower bound of $A$. Let $c\in C$. There exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $c=\frac{n^2+12n+32}{n+5}$.
$$\frac{45}{6}\leq\frac{n^2+12n+32}{n+5}\iff...\iff11\leq2n^2+9n$$To prove that $\frac{45}{6}$ is infimum, it is sufficient to show $\forall \epsilon>0\quad \exists c\in C\quad(c<\epsilon+\inf C) $.
Using $$\frac{n_0^2+12n_0+32}{n_0+5}<\epsilon+\frac{45}{6}$$I wasn't able to find such $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ that would do the job.

Comment: $$n_0=1{}{}{}$$

Comment: $\dfrac{45}{6}=\dfrac{15}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^2+12x+32}{x+5}=x+7-\frac3{x+5}$. Then $f'(x)=1+\frac3{(x+5)^2}>0$. So, $f$ is strictly increasing and therefore$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f(n)\geqslant f(1)=\frac{45}6.$$

Comment: This is a good answer. Is there a different approach using just inequalities (i.e finding some $r$ which has $n$ in it s.t. $\frac{n_0^2+12n_0+32}{n_0+5}<r<\epsilon+\frac{45}{6}$) that you may know of? (We're not yet allowed to know what functions are)

Comment: @SlavikEgorov Just use the fact that $n>1\implies\frac3{n+5}<\frac3{1+5}=\frac12$. It follows from this that$$n>1\implies n+7-\frac3{n+5}>1+7-\frac12=\frac{15}2=\frac{45}6.$$

Answer (score 1):

To answer to the question raised in a comment, it can be solved just using properties of inequalities: in the decomposition of
$$ f(n)=\frac{n^2+12n+32}{n+5}=n+7 -\frac 3{n+5}, $$
note $n+5$ is *increasing*, so as  it is positive for all $n\in\mathbf N$, $\dfrac 3{n+5}$ is *decreasing*, and $-\dfrac 3{n+5}$ is (again) *increasing*.

Thus $f(n)$, which is the sum of two increasing functions, is increasing.

*Edit*: B.t.w., as $\mathbf N$ contains $0$, the minimum should be $\dfrac{32}5$.

Comment: What implies that $0$ is necessarily in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Independently from historical reasons  (it was introduced in Western Europe around the 11th century, coming from India), the reasons are Peano's axioms, Bourbaki's treatise and the construction of ordinals, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

$$\iff n^2+n(12-C)+32-5C=0$$ which is a quadratic equation in $n$

As $n$ is real, $$(12-C)^2\ge4(32-5C)\iff21C^2-24C+16\ge0$$